# django-rest-framework custom error message as response

Tags: error-handling, django-rest-framework

For my API, I need to respond every request's error with HTTP 200 and a JSON content. So instead of, responding with this:

```
Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I'd like to do this:

```
res = {"code": 400, "message": "Bad Requset"}
Response(res)
```

Where is the best place to put such thing and how? In `Serializer`, `Renderer`, `Exception`? I need to catch every exception that serializer might throw as well as custom exception that I have written.

Answer (score 10):

You may use status code **200** and with `data=json.dumps(...)`, something like this:

```
res = {"code": 400, "message": "Bad Requset"}
return Response(data=json.dumps(res), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In terms of where to handle the exception, RestFramework has it covered, read [Exceptions - Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/), you can create a custom handler and do so.

However as api end points normally will be per view base, I would personally recommend create a custom decorator to wrap your views and return such Response in case of error.
Or, if you really want to return same response on **ALL** errors, then follow RestFramework doc and customise your error handling should be the best practice.

Hope this helps.